# Can things go wrong if we declare objects to be arrows?

Tags: soft-question, category-theory

I am familiar with categories and also with 'categories without objects'. In fact a category is completely determined by its set of arrows and the objects can be missed. Nevertheless the objects are convenient when it comes to visualisation and have a function in making abstract nonsense a bit less abstract. Normally however I tend to avoid redundancies and in this context the following question arose:

> Can anything go 'wrong' if we just interpret the set of objects always as a subset of the set of arrows?

Here off course the objects are identified with the identity-arrows. If this can be practicized then we don't really 'lose' the objects and at the same time we can work in a category without redundancies.

Comment: Yes, you can axiomatize category theory solely with a primitive notion of arrows, among which are a special case of "identity arrows".  I recall this being mentioned in previous posts about axioms for category theory, or perhaps it was more history of category theory.

Comment: I think you answer your question yourself. If this subset of the set of arrows is exactly the set of identity arrows, then nothing can go wrong. :)

Comment: Here's [the post I remembered](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/271315/3111) that mentions Eilenberg and MacLane's 1945 exposition noted the possibility of dispensing with objects (in favor of an arrows-only approach).

Comment: You can safely declare $X = \mathrm{id}_X$ for all objects $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what [Eilenberg and MacLane noted (p.238) in their seminal 1945 paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1945-058-00/S0002-9947-1945-0013131-6/S0002-9947-1945-0013131-6.pdf):

> > [Axioms C4-C5] assert that the rule $A\rightarrow e_A$ provides a one-to-one correspondence between the set of all objects of the category and the set of all its identity mappings. It is thus clear that the objects play a secondary role, and could  be entirely omitted from the definition of a category. However, the manipulation of the applications would be slightly less convenient if this were done.

Answer (score 2):

No, nothing can go wrong, but also it doesn't make life easier. After all, you want to work with morphisms from one object to another object, so that you really need the notion of an object (even if this can be encoded as a morphism). Also, the composition of morphisms is only defined when the first morphism ends where the second morphism starts - and it is good to know when this happens. I'm not aware of any situation where the "object-free" notion of a category is useful.